# I am able to make exe of my pyttsx3 file but i am unable to send my exe

Tags: python, python-3.x, artificial-intelligence, google-cloud-speech, pyttsx3

I had worked to make A.I Base assistant and i was successful to make exe file but i am unable to send exe files to others as this error comes "missing pyttsx3 drivers ".I was successful to make it exe by writing this code in my spec file [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gWjeN.png)
but when i send it to my other laptop same error comes"missing pyttsx3 drivers"

Answer (score 1):

If you are converting using PyInstaller, then:
First You have to go to `C:\Users\YourUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks` and search for `hook-pyttsx3.py` If found try again. If not found, then create a python file named `hook-pyttsx3.py` then write

```
hiddenimports = [
    'pyttsx3.drivers',
    'pyttsx3.drivers.dummy',
    'pyttsx3.drivers.espeak',
    'pyttsx3.drivers.nsss',
    'pyttsx3.drivers.sapi5', ]
```

Video Tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GFMZyHi28oM

Thank You,